# (Action Script 3) Getting click location when context menu opens

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to get the location of the click when I open the ContextMenu via right+click using AS3 and flash.

I've tried using the MouseEvent.Context_Menu:

```
mapSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, OnContextMenuOpening);
```

This does fire on right+click but the context menu no longer opens.

I have also tried using the MosueEvent.Right_Click:

```
mapSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, OnContextMenuOpening);
```

That to fires on right+click but prevents the context menu from opening.

Anyone have any insight into the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atriace's answer is basically correct, but it didn't quite address the actual question directly enough for me to realize it immediately.  Here is a little expansion on his solution:

```
private function setupSample():void
{
     // NOTE: Sample assumes that I have a TextField named _myTextField defined elsewhere.
     _myTextField.contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
     _myTextField.contextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, hContextMenuSelect);
}

private function hContextMenuSelect(pEvent:ContextMenuEvent):void
{
      var x:Number = pEvent.mouseTarget.mouseX;
      var y:Number = pEvent.mouseTarget.mouseY;
}
```

Using this approach, the context menu will actually be displayed, but you will also get access to the coordinates of the mouse click.  Just add the ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT listener directly to the context menu and extract the point from the listener argument. Note that the mouse position is available through the ContextMenuEvent.

Answer (score 2):

Not what I would consider ideal, but this will get you exactly that.  Create a new menu object (which has all the built-in menu options), and add an event listener to it.

```
var my_menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu = my_menu;
my_menu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, rightClicker)

function rightClicker(e:ContextMenuEvent):void {
    trace(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working. I have created a 300x300 shape and assigned context menu on it. The mouse position will be displayed in the text box in top-left corner.

```
package {
import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.display.Shape;

/**
 * ...
 * @author GR
 */
public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var cm_item1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Menu Item 1");
    private var cm_item2:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Menu Item 2");
    private var cm_item3:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Menu Item 3");
    private var cm_item4:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Menu Item 4");
    private var txtFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 20, 0x000000);
    private var c_menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    private var map_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    private var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    private var bg:Shape = new Shape();

    public function Main():void {
        bg.graphics.beginFill(0x00ffff);
        bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        bg.graphics.endFill();
        map_mc.addChild(bg);
        map_mc.x = map_mc.y = 100;
        addChild(map_mc);

        txt.background = 0xffffff;
        txt.border = true;
        txt.defaultTextFormat = txtFormat;
        txt.width = 200;
        addChild(txt);

        c_menu.hideBuiltInItems();
        c_menu.customItems.push(cm_item1, cm_item2, cm_item3, cm_item4);
        map_mc.contextMenu = c_menu;

        map_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, cmFx);
    }

    private function cmFx(e:MouseEvent):void {
        txt.text = "x: " + mouseX + " y: " + mouseY; 
    }

}
```

}